# In TensorflowLite, the OpenCL delegate generates a large numerical error

Tags: tensorflow, opencl, tensorflow-lite

I converted a model from Keras to Tensorflow Lite and tried running the model on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Android 11 (on a Qualcomm based Samsung Galaxy S20), CPU only. In both cases I get near identical results as original Keras model.

However, when I try to use an OpenCL delegate, I get incorrect results. On Ubuntu (with an NVidia GPU and OpenCL libs provided by CUDA SDK), the results present large numerical errors. For example, I was expecting to get [-0.00202503, 0.410477, 0.0156457, 0.937922, -0.00748677, ...], instead I got [-0.00182705, 0.36573794, 0.01720826, 0.926801, 7.88331e-05, ...]. On Qualcomm Snapdragon, I would get all nan's.

I suspected the problem might be related to FP16 precision computation. I tried to disable FP16 by doing:

```
        TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2 options;
        options.is_precision_loss_allowed = 0;
        options.inference_preference = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PREFERENCE_FAST_SINGLE_ANSWER;
        options.inference_priority1 = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_MIN_LATENCY;
        options.inference_priority2 = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_MAX_PRECISION;
        options.inference_priority3 = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_MIN_MEMORY_USAGE;
        options.experimental_flags = TFLITE_GPU_EXPERIMENTAL_FLAGS_CL_ONLY;
        
        auto* delegate = TfLiteGpuDelegateV2Create(&options);
```

But I failed to notice any effect setting `is_precision_loss_allowed` to zero or non-zero has on the output. Is this not the correct way to control the compute precision in GPU delegate?

Another thing I suspect is that there are a few tanh and sigmoid activations towards the end of my model (aside from those, my model only contains fully connected, batch norm, and elementwise addition/multiplications). I peaked at the layer right before the first tanh activation and the output of that layer is still very close (within numerical precision) to what I expected. Is there any known issues with the tanh or sigmoid activation layer in GPU delegate? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I would strongly suggested to post an Issue on TensorFlow Github repo. In the past, I had an experience with numerical bugs in Hexagon Delegate. After sharing my problem :https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36927 my issue was resolved within few days.

Answer (score 0):

Use TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_MAX_PRECISION as inference_priority1 otherwise it will trigger FP16 which can result in accuracy drop.